# Applying a scaling animation to a large array/group of objects

Tags: animation, modifiers, transforms

I am attempting to make an animation where hundreds of similar objects appear on a specified area of the world with a simple scaling animation as shown below:

[image]

However I only know how to make this manually by copying each individual object by hand and moving the keyframes manually, which naturally is too time consuming:

The array modifier would probably be closest to what I am looking for. but I don't know how, or if it is even possible to apply a scaling animation to the arrayed objects.

[image]

So my question is, what would be the simplest and the most efficient way to make hundreds of similar objects appear by "popping up" as shown in the first animation?

Comment: i would recommend using the free commotion add-on

Comment: @Chris it looks like a good add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with *Geometry Nodes*. Instance a cube along a *Curve Line*, then move an *Empty* along this line and scale the cubes according to their position relative to the *Empty* by subtracting the cube's position from the location of the *Empty*. Then maybe add a *Map Range* node to make it scale slower or quicker to your liking.

[image: scaling cubes animation]

This is my node setup:

[image: scaling cubes node setup]

PS: Of course you could instance other objects and even complete collections this way instead of a cube. And with more complex setups you could even use other than straight curves.

Thinking a little bit about the arbitrary curves, it's actually not a very complex setup to do it (rather less complex):

[image: scaling along arbitrary curve]

This is the node setup where you can simply use any curve object:

[image: scaling cubes 2]

Comment: clamp in this case make things easy. :)

Comment: @NatureK Depending on what you want to achieve clamping is either mandatory or not necessary at all or even contrary to what you need.

Comment: +1 ...and even with preview gif....very nice ! ;) i wish i could do that with geometry nodes.... :D

Comment: @Chris most of the time I get the impression you can do more in GN than me... ;) Made a quick edit

Comment: that's just an impression....don't let you fool by impressions... ;)

Comment: @Oishin You already accepted the answer, but I added something more independent from the straight line.

Comment: one more thing: if you have a GN node setup as Gordon made it where the curve is the input geometry, you can go in edit mode, press this button [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI29J.png and then you can draw your path like a pencil: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5triI.gif

Comment: @Chris Good addition. You can even draw or extrude curves while the animation is running :) And maybe you would then want to change the _Resample Curve_ node to "Length" instead of "Count", so that you get more instances if a curve is longer and less when the curve is shorter.

Comment: ok....show me what you can (i didn't make although i thought it is simple math: make the distance between the cubes all equal, no matter how long the curve is. i tried dividing length through distance (just a value) and plug into resample curve - won't work - i have no idea why). And really weird: if you paint an extra curve, the result is even weirder....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135229/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-chris).